# How to get value from key in a map, where the key is an adress?

Tags: solidity, javascript, mapping

Im a bit struggling with all the datatypes in solidity so i hope someone can help me out.

I created a map where i can store a specific adress + value(number) trough a public function. Now i am writing anotherfunction to actually check a given adress and see what value the adress holds. But for some reason i cant get the proper datatype i think to be able to get to the right spot inside the map (on the requested adress).
The function i use to write to the map:

```
function setMap(address[] calldata addresses, uint8 value) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            _addressMap[addresses[i]] =  value;
        }
}
```

//

```
function checkMap(address[] calldata checkAdress) public {

        return _addressMap[checkAdress];
    
}
```

I am looking for a way to check the value of a specific adress from my frontend javascriptcode with a .call, so i was trying to make something like checkMap(adressvalue),  But it seems i cant get the argument for checkMap in the correct datatype to retreive the value and make it match, or my backend code in the contract is just totally wrong at all since it keeps giving me errors with mismatching datatypes. Anyone has a solution or example for my above scenario and how to retreive the values from the address key?

```
_adressMap[msg.sender]
```

is working fine btw to get the value, thats why i think its a datatype problem. But i dont want to check the msg.sender but a specific given custom adress.

Hope someone cal help me out, i dont do solidity very long yet so im probably doing something stupid. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `checkMap()` to:

```
function checkMap(address checkAdress) public returns (uint8) {
    return _addressMap[checkAdress];
}
```

If you want to access the `uint8` value stored at `_addressMap[<address>]` the parameter `checkAdress` shouldn't be of data type `address[]`, additionally, you must explicitly specify return data type if you want your function to return a value of data type `uint8`.

*Edit: Added how to call `checkMap()` in js without producing a transaction.*

```
//init contract
var contractAbi = <contract abi>;
var contractAddress = <contract address>;
var contract = new pWeb3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

//call checkMap()
try {
    var addressToLookup = <address>;
    await contract.methods.checkMap(addressToLookup).call(function(checkMapError, checkMapResult) {
        if(checkMapError == null) {
            console.log("checkMap() call result: " + checkMapResult);
        } else {
            console.log("checkMap() error: " + checkMapError.message);
        }
    });
} catch(checkMapException) {
    console.log("checkMap() exception: " + checkMapException.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked like a charm. It does require a transaction and gas cost tho. Is there also a way to make it possible without gasfees just so its possible to do a .call from the frontend javascript?

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain an example of calling `checkMap()` via js without producing a tx (i.e. a `read-only` call of which consumes zero gas).

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. You really helped me a bunch of understanding the js->contract interaction better. Going to experiment a bit more with it.. The code works perfect! Thanks again.